# How can I count the number of visitors that come to my Google Form?

Tags: html, google-forms

I want to measure the traffic on my Google Form, even if the visitor does not finish the form. 
I can count  the numbers of rows inside the results document, but it won't give the real number of visitors.

Comment: I don't believe that there is a way to capture the number of times the URL to the form was loaded in the browser, whether they submitted the form or not.  Is the form embedded in a website?  Is it being emailed to people?

Comment: No, just a shorted link to reach the form will be given to people. My aim is only to know how much people went on the link I gave them (Social experiment), maybe Google Form isn't the best choice for that.

Comment: I use a third party simple tool https://www.trackyourform.com and that works like a charm for me!

Answer (score -1):

You can simply add a Google Analytics tracking code to your form using https://GFormAnalytics.com

It wrap the form in an iframe for you and then you can track what's going on in your forms.